# Firefox 43 seems to have broken W3C (navigator.geolocation) location services

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, geolocation

I've just upgraded to Firefox 43 and the HTML5/W3C location service on my site no longer works.

I've checked the [release notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/43) for 43 and can find no reference to any changes.

This is the JS that I'm using to get the current Lat/Long location:

```
// Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) { // start of callback function for success
    alert("ok");
    }, 
    function () {  // start of callback function for getPos failure
                alert("Unable to determine your current location");
    }); // end of get position call
} else { // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
     alert("Geolocation not available");
}
```

and here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15mosxbe/) showing that in Firefox 43 I get the 'unable to determine' error, rather than geolocation not available...

Note, geolocation still seems to be working in Chrome with the above, and Firefox 43 on Android is still working without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit strange...

With the download of the v43.0.1 update this problem resolved itself *before* the update was applied!

There is no mention in the 43.0.1 release notes of any change that would affect geolocation either, but the problem has definitely resolved.

Comment: The problem seems to have returned for me with v43.04

Comment: Agree, I can confirm that this problem has returned with the v43.0.4 update for me as well.

Comment: But is suddenly working again now... this is strange - it seems to stop working for a while after an upgrade, but then sorts itself out.